# php UTF-8 encoding of a string using utf8_encode() gives the same string as result

Tags: php, utf-8, utf

I am using this utf8_encode() function in php (using the online editor http://www.writephponline.com/). The problem is that I am getting the same string as a result. Am I doing something wrong... very very new to php. Looking for some guidance with respect to what is the correct result.

Example:

```
echo utf8_encode("a6ab35d3-905b-4d1e-a967-169c1aa2dd56d337e8bd-d6ae-4f3b-a4b6-0980dcbeb632");
```

Result is `a6ab35d3-905b-4d1e-a967-169c1aa2dd56d337e8bd-d6ae-4f3b-a4b6-0980dcbeb632`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the characters in your string are the same in utf8 as in ASCII.  Utf-8 is a variable-length encoding that stores the same values as ASCII for character codes 32 - 127.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Try adding some accented characters to your test string.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try to explore it a bit more.!